# Rest to filter files using modified date

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using below api to get files in descending order of modified date, but it not working.

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('EmployeeDocumentList/703079322')?$expand=Files/ListItemAllFields&$orderby=TimeLastModified desc";
```

Is there anything that I am missing over here?

Comment: do you mean ascending order or descending ? If you want ascending order, just remove the `desc` at the end

Comment: I have updated the question, I need it in descending order

Answer (score 0):

Internal name for Modified Item Date is `Modified`.

Hence, your query should be:

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('EmployeeDocumentList/703079322')?$expand=Files/ListItemAllFields&$orderby=Modified desc";
```